# HTAccess to Allow specific IP Range

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I'm trying to deny all and only allow a specific range. I have read that you can allow a range by only entereing a partial IP address, but this is not what I'm looking to do.

For example, I would like to only allow a specific IP range of, say, 192.168.1.33 through 192.168.1.65.  I want to deny everything less than or equal to 192.168.1.32 and greater than or equal to 192.168.1.66

I have no way to test the following, but will this work? If not, what's the best solution to accomplish this?

```
Deny from All
Allow from 192.168.1.33-65
```

Answer (score 0):

If the range you want to allow matches a network CIDR pattern like `192.168.1.0/24` then you can indeed specify it as such. If it's an arbitrary range of IP addresses that doesn't fall neatly into a block like that then you're stuck enumerating them.